# Does Selenium integrate "independent" browsers (via webdrivers) or use existing browsers installed in the OS?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new the Cross Browser Testing and just starting to look at Selenium however I can't seem to find the answer to the followings on the official site. It would be much appreciated if someone can help clarify for me.

1. Does Selenium integrate "independent browsers" (via webdrivers) or uses/links existing browsers installed in the OS?
2. If Selenium uses "independent browsers", can it actually "open" for instance say IE7, IE8, IE9, IE10, Safari in OS (say windows) separately after which you can test the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The browsers that you want to be tested should be installed in your machine. so the answer is it uses existing browsers.

2) No. You have misunderstood.It can automate only the browsers available in the OS. BTW, you can not have multiple version of same browsers in same machine... unless you run from a pen drive.

Comment: Thanks! I used to think running selenium would be like running "thinapp" version of each browsers without vmware like environment.

Answer (score 0):

Using RemoteWebDriver and Selenium Grid, you can have different machines hosting different versions of browsers.

The tests will still execute on your machine but the browser will open on a machine which has the version you define in the test.

This is especially useful when running tests as part of a CI build when the CI server will often not have browsers installed.

Building and maintaining your own grid can be time consuming so companies such as Saucelabs provide a cloud solution in which you point your tests to open browsers on their grid. They have most combination of browsers, versions and os.

Comment: It will be time consuming to build something like that. You are right.